# Why can't I set object on `user`? -- Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: parse-platform

Here's my code:

```
  var user = Parse.User.current();

  if (user.isCurrent()) {
    console.log("exports.saveLevel -- isCurrent");
  };


 if (user.authenticated()) {
    console.log("exports.saveLevel -- authenticated");
  };

  var language = req.body.language;
  var level = req.body.level;
  var key = "level_" + language.code;

  console.log("exports.saveLevel -- language.code = " + language.code);
  console.log("exports.saveLevel -- level = " + level);

  // Save the level
  user.set(key, level);

  user.save().then(
    function(obj) {
      console.log("exports.saveLevel -- saved -- obj = " + obj);
      res.send({status: 200});
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("exports.saveLevel -- error = " + error);
      res.send({status: 500});
    }
  );
```

Here are the logs. I know all my objects are there, and user is `authenticated`:

```
19:16:19 web.1  | exports.saveLevel -- isCurrent
19:16:19 web.1  | exports.saveLevel -- authenticated
19:16:19 web.1  | exports.saveLevel -- langauge = [object Object]
19:16:19 web.1  | exports.saveLevel -- langauge.code = fr
19:16:19 web.1  | exports.saveLevel -- level = [object Object]
19:16:19 web.1  | exports.saveLevel -- level.name = Child
19:16:19 web.1  | POST /saveLevel 500 44ms - 59b
```

But I get a `500 status code` and no other error information.

---

Here's the log of `console.log(level)`:

```
10:01:08 web.1  | { level: '1',
10:01:08 web.1  |   name: 'Child',
10:01:08 web.1  |   name_en: 'Child',
10:01:08 web.1  |   ACL: 
10:01:08 web.1  |    { '*': { read: 'true' },
10:01:08 web.1  |      'role:Administrators': { write: 'true' },
10:01:08 web.1  |      giLkokRpuK: { write: 'true', read: 'true' } },
10:01:08 web.1  |   objectId: 'b9KaEwoWOV',
10:01:08 web.1  |   createdAt: '2014-04-17T17:41:25.401Z',
10:01:08 web.1  |   updatedAt: '2014-04-23T23:03:43.964Z' }
```

And `console.log(language)`:

```
10:01:08 web.1  | { code: 'fr',
10:01:08 web.1  |   isSetup: 'true',
10:01:08 web.1  |   name: 'French',
10:01:08 web.1  |   nativeSpelling: 'français',
10:01:08 web.1  |   order: '130',
10:01:08 web.1  |   languageObjectsNative: 
10:01:08 web.1  |    [ { __type: 'Pointer',
10:01:08 web.1  |        className: 'Language',
10:01:08 web.1  |        objectId: 'GQPAHePPl3' } ],
10:01:08 web.1  |   users: { __type: 'Relation', className: '_User' },
10:01:08 web.1  |   usersNative: { __type: 'Relation', className: '_User' },
10:01:08 web.1  |   objectId: 'GQPAHePPl3',
10:01:08 web.1  |   createdAt: '2013-11-15T22:11:16.368Z',
10:01:08 web.1  |   updatedAt: '2014-07-06T03:00:29.380Z' }
```

Comment: console.log(level); console.log(language);  What type are they supposed to be?

Comment: `level` and `language` are both objects. So I'm taking `language.code` and using that as part of the key, and `level` is the object to be pointed to by that key.

Comment: what kind of objects?  can you share a console.log(level) and console.log(language) ?

Comment: `exports.saveLevel -- level = [object Object]`... They're Parse objects that I retrieved server-side. I then passed them to the client... When the user selects a level I'm passing that `level` object back to the server in an AJAX post to save... Is the problem that this object is no longer a Parse object and just a regular JS object?

Comment: Sorry. `console.log(level)` logs to `[object Object]`

Comment: it should not log to `[object Object]` if passed to console.log by itself, it only should do that if you're using some string with it like in your example code.  log it out by itself.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-security  some notes there about using "authenticated method" to return _User...

Comment: @Fosco Sorry, I didn't realize that adding a string would do that. I've now included the log of `console.log(level)` in the question.

Comment: @RobertRowntree. I'm using the `become` method after passing a `sessionToken`. Also, if I log out `user.isCurrent()` or `ser.authenticated()` after `become` they both log true, so it appears that's not the issue.

Comment: So if level/language were parse objects, what happened to them since fetching them originally?  They are missing some special fields, __type, className..  The issue might be that the column accepts Pointer<someClass> and you're just sending a json object.

Comment: @Fosco. That was exactly the issue. The Parse object became a regular JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` You can read more about it **[here](https://www.parse.com/questions/what-is-the-scope-of-using-parsecloudusemasterkey-in-cloud-code).**